# How can I fix `"main::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" used only once` warnings when using Perl's Win32::Registry?

Tags: perl, registry, warnings

I have a script that would get a registry key value. Here's the code.

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $winRegistryStatus=0;

    eval {
       require Win32::Registry;
       Win32::Registry->import();
    };
    unless($@) {
       $winRegistryStatus=1;
    }

    my $registryPath = "Self\Random";
    my $keyName = "Configure";
    my $registryKeySettings;
    my %registrySubKeyValues;

    $main::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Open($registryPath, $registryKeySettings) || die "Cannot open $registryPath: $!";
    $registryKeySettings->GetValues(\%registrySubKeyValues); # get sub keys and value -hash ref
    foreach my $subKey (keys %registrySubKeyValues) {
        my $_subKey = $registrySubKeyValues{$subKey};
        next unless $$_subKey[0] eq $keyName;
        print "Configure=" . $$_subKey[2];
    }
```

Output

```
   Name "main::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" used only once: possible typo at ....
   Configure=Yes
```

I could get the value of Configure but it also returns a warning which I don't know how to fix it.

Any body where am I wrong and could show me how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: The "used only once" is a warning that `use warnings` issues because you have used `$main::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` only once. In your case, you can either ignore it, or simply deactivate that kind of warning: `no warnings 'once'`. What is the other warning?

Comment: No other warnings. Could you post your answer please. Thank you :D

Comment: `Win32::Registry` - accessing the Windows registry **[obsolete, use `Win32::TieRegistry`]** (emphasis mine)

Comment: @SinanÜnür So I've heard. But right now, I am limited to use Win32::Registry.

Comment: @quinekxi: that is a strange limitation. I guess it's someone's idea of a standard but it's a dreadful one. Win32::Registry isn't even a core module so someone had to *choose* to install it.

Comment: @Borodin Yeah, I was thinking that I would suggest to the team who delivers the cygwin Perl package to us to include Win32::TieRegistry.

Comment: @quinekxi: can you not just install it?

Comment: @Borodin I can install it if I want but its not part of the scope of my project because there is other team who delivers the cygwin Perl to us, it still needs an approval to install another module.

Comment: @quinekxi: well you have a good case as the `Win32::Registry` POD itself recommends that you should use `Win32::TieRegistry` instead!

Comment: @Borodin: Maybe on next release, I can work on it. (today is the deadline). Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module is rather odd in that it exports symbols to the `main` package regardless of where it is used from.

But in your case this is what you want: your program is in `main` as you have no `package` statement, and you can omit the `main::` from `$HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

As to your problem, the code you show doesn't raise the warning you say it does. The problem must be somewhere else. Please would you show your full code so that we can advise you better.

In the mean time please pay heed to @Sinan Ünür's advice - [`Win32::TieRegistry`](http://p3rl.org/Win32%3a%3aTieRegistry) is preferable to `Win32::Registry`. Even the POD documentation of `Win32::Registry` says this:

> NOTE: This module provides a very klunky interface to access the
>   Windows registry, and is not currently being developed actively.  It
>   only exists for backward compatibility with old code that uses it. For
>   more powerful and flexible ways to access the registry, use
>   Win32::TieRegistry.

---

**Update**

I understand the problem having seen the update to your question and it is because you are executing the `require Win32::Registry` at run time. That means that `$HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` doesn't exist at compile time and so the compiler complains about it.

The fix is to declare it at compile time with

```
our $HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

at the top of the program.

By the way there is no need for the `import` call if all you need is this scalar.

Comment: I've also read it in some other questions/posts. But its part of the limitation. I am only bounded to use Win32::Registry.

Answer (score 4):

The "used only once" is a warning that `use warnings` issues because you have used `$main::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` only once. You are not at fault here. It is a mere hint that you might have forgotten something.

In this case, you can either ignore it, or simply deactivate that kind of warning: no warnings 'once'.

In general it is a good idea to enclose these things in a `BLOCK` and add a long, descriptive comment to it that explains why you are turning off that kind of warning here.

```
{ # Disable 'used only once' warning because the $::HKEY_...
  # var was imported by Win32::Registry and is not used anywhere else.
  $main::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Open($registryPath, $registryKeySettings) 
    || die "Cannot open $registryPath: $!";
}
```

You can find more infos about `warnings` [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).